# cocos2dx 3.x schedule error

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

When I try implement add one node per n seconds, the procedure crashes.

if I just run `runBlock(0.0f)`, the procedure runs normally.

This is my code

**MainLayer.cpp**

```
bool MainLayer::init(){
   if (!Layer::init()){
    return false;
   }
   block_array = new std::vector<block*>();

   Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();

   auto body = PhysicsBody::createEdgeBox(visibleSize,PHYSICSBODY_MATERIAL_DEFAULT, 3.0); 
   body->setCategoryBitmask(0x0001);
   body->setCollisionBitmask(0x0001);
   body->setContactTestBitmask(0x0000);
   body->getShape(0)->setRestitution(0.0);

   auto edgeNode = Node::create();
   edgeNode->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width / 2, visibleSize.height / 2));
   edgeNode->setPhysicsBody(body);
   this->addChild(edgeNode);


   auto sp = Sprite::create("CloseNormal.png");
   sp->setTag(PLAYER);
   auto sp_body = PhysicsBody::createCircle(sp->getContentSize().width / 2);
   sp_body->setCategoryBitmask(0x003);
   sp_body->setCollisionBitmask(0x003);
   sp_body->setContactTestBitmask(0x001);
   sp->setPhysicsBody(sp_body);
   sp->setPosition(visibleSize / 2);
   this->addChild(sp);

   initBlock();
   /**
     When run function "runBlock", process crash!!
   */
   schedule(schedule_selector(MainLayer::runBlock), 5.0f, CC_REPEAT_FOREVER, 0.0f);

  //runBlock(0.0f);     if just run it, everything is right
   return true;
}


 void MainLayer::initBlock(){
   block_array->push_back(new block1());          //block is other class, it has no problem
   block_array->push_back(new block2());
   block_array->push_back(new block3());
 }

void MainLayer::runBlock(float dt){
   Size size = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
   int len = block_array->size();
   block* bl;
   do 
   {
       int rand = floor(CCRANDOM_0_1()*len);
       if (rand == len){
           rand -= 1;
       }

       bl = (*block_array)[rand];
   } while (bl->node->getParent());            //Crash in here!!!!!

   bl->come(Vec2(size.width*1.5, 0));
   this->addChild(bl->node);
```

}

I use VS2013. The error info is

```
Without exception handling in 0x009D5402(in test.exe)  0xC0000005:  Access violation when reading location 0xFEEF0012
```

I have debug.  "bl->node" is allocated memory. So I don't think it is NULL pointer error. However, I don't know what reason cause the crash.

Please help me, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After a few frames all your blocks will have parents and the while loop will never exit.

I don't really understand what it is you're trying to accomplish here, but might I suggest keeping two arrays, filling the first in initBlocks(), randomly picking one in runBlock(), processing it, and moving it to the second array.

This way you don't need the while loop, which wastes a lot of time if you keep picking a block that you've already processed.

Comment: I want to accomplish several different category block which come from the right of viewport over and over again.   And I don't think the root of problem is the while loop never exit. Because I use "bl = (*block_array)[0]", instead of the while loop, the problem still exists

Comment: while (bl->node->getParent()); will always be true if your block is already added to the layer. This will cause an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
void MainLayer::runBlock(float dt)
{ 
    Size size = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();

    //waiting_block_array = block_array when you initialize

   if (waiting_block_array)
   {
        int rand = random (0, waiting_block_array.size () - 1);
        addChild (waiting_block_array[rand]);
        waiting_block_array[rand]->come(Vec2(size.width*1.5, 0));
        this->addChild(waiting_block_array[rand]->node);
        waiting_block_array.erase (waiting_block_array.begin () + rand);
    }
```

Comment: your mean I should clone block_array to waiting_block_array? I don't really understand the waiting_block_array. By the way, block_array is a static vector, and what i want to accomplish is several different category block which come from the right of viewport over and over again

Comment: Think of waiting_block_array as a vector of blocks that is waiting to be added to the layer.

Comment: I have found the crash reason !  After initalization and 5 seconds , bl->node = NULL. I have modified my code but problem still exists. You can see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066542/what-is-the-memory-management-in-cocos2dx-3-10)